# Can't POST to C# WebAPI server created while following tutorial

Tags: c#, http, visual-studio-code, post, webapi

I'm following along [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code) to create a Web API using C#, and I have across an issue. The GET handler is working fine but the POST handler seems to be having issues parsing the body. Whenever I make a GET request, I get a valid response back (photos below), but if I try a POST of PUT, I get a `415 HTTP` error.
This is my model:

```
public class Pet
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public string? Name {get; set;}
  public string? Type {get; set;}
  public string? Breed {get; set;}
  public string? Description {get; set;}
  public string? BirthDate {get; set;}
  public string? ImageUrl {get; set;}
  public long? Adopter {get; set;} = null;
  public bool Available {get; set;} = false;
}
```

This is the corresponding controller:

```
public class PetsController : ControllerBase {
  ...
  
  // The handler for POST
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<ActionResult<Pet>> PostPet([FromBody]Pet pet)
  {
      _context.Pet.Add(pet);
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

      return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetPet), new { id = pet.Id }, pet);
  }      

  ...
}
```

Here is a GET request response.

[image: GET request result]

And here is a POST request response.
[image: POST request result]

This is the payload I'm sending.

[image]

Complete JSON response (for POST).

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-298784fa1ee54a98afe19a0db7410d23-6cef112f5fc292b1-00",
  "errors":{
    "$":[
          "'-' is invalid within a number, immediately after a sign character ('+' or '-'). Expected a digit ('0'-'9'). Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
    ],
    "pet":[
          "The pet field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to resolve this:

Change `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]` in your controllers method signature:

[image: image showing [From Form] being used to bind values]

Or, don't use a form, and instead use a POST body in JSON.

For example:

```json
{
    "name": "allan",
    "type": "cat",
    "breed": "husky",
    "description": "a nice doggy",
    "birthDate": "12/12/2009",
    "imageUrl": "dog.png"
}
```

This should bind the values properly:

[image: image showing post controller binding body to class]

Comment: Note, you should use a `DateTime?` type for `birthDate` as well, so you don't have to handle dates as strings.